# jQuery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Getting a weird error on a site I am developing. Even looked back at last couple of sites to make sure there was no differences... and nope, can not see any.

Getting an jQuery undefined error only in IE on the following page http://weesleekit.info/lotus/beta/ it's with regard to the easy slider part on the site, but have used easy slider multiple times before and never ever had an issue.

Can anyone shed some light into this, I am racking my brains and seem to be finding nothing.

Comment: Well, for starters there's an unclosed tag for the screen.css file in the header, add a closing bracket there.

Comment: I have had problems with IE and the hover function when it's only being passed one argument. Have you tried adding a no-op "function(){}" as the second parameter to your first hover call?

Comment: Also happens on chrome: rendered HTML is: `<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" <script="" src="js/easySlider1.7.js">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" /

  ><script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
```

There are several lines in between your `/` and `>` that shouldn't be there, and IE isn't including the `<script>` block that follows it.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if this is related, but in the source of that site, before jquery.js is included there is an unclosed:

`<link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">`

(make it: ```)

maybe IE is bugging out and not including jQuery since it is technically inside the `<link>` element. See if fixing that does anything (i kinda doubt it)

and a comment by @burningstar4 says that there is a link which is missing a closing tag as well:

`<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" /`

should be

`<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" />`